# C# - Image size increases after creating a smaller resolution of the same image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm unable to see why this code creates a thumbnail of an image that was previously 1280x800 with a size of 241kb to 600x375 with a size of 556kb. Here is the code:

```
using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"c:\images\myImg.jpg"))
{
    int sourceWidth = img.Width;
    int sourceHeight = img.Height;
    int thumbHeight, thumbWidth = 0;
    decimal ratio = decimal.Divide(sourceHeight, sourceWidth);
    if (sourceHeight > 600 || sourceWidth > 800)
    {
        if (ratio >= 1) // Image is higher than it is wide.
        {
            thumbHeight = 800;
            thumbWidth = Convert.ToInt32(decimal.Divide(sourceWidth, sourceHeight) * thumbHeight);
        }
        else // Image is wider than it is high.
        {
            thumbWidth = 600;
            thumbHeight = Convert.ToInt32(decimal.Divide(sourceHeight, sourceWidth) * thumbWidth);
        }

        using (Bitmap bMap = new Bitmap(thumbWidth, thumbHeight))
        {
            Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bMap);

            gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;

            Rectangle rectDestination = new Rectangle(0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight);

            gr.DrawImage(img, rectDestination, 0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            bMap.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/i/" + filename + "_" + fileExtension));
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you kindly,
Ben

Comment: Changing the *size* is not the same thing as changing the *resolution* of the image. 

All you've done by making the picture smaller in size is cause more pixels to be packed into less space.

Comment: Most likely, the compression quality of the input image is low, while the compression quality of the output image is high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saving an image that used to be compressed using jpeg compression as a bitmap image that has no compression.  The offending line is here:

```
bMap.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server
                     .MapPath("~/i/" + filename + "_" + fileExtension));
```

Just because you're saving it with a different file extension doesn't make the resulting image file a jpeg image.  You need to use one of the [`Bitmap.Save` overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.save.aspx) that specifies the format of the image you would like to save it as.  For example

```
//Creating a second variable just for readability sake.
var resizedFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server
             .MapPath("~/i/" + filename + "_" + fileExtension);
bMap.Save(resizedFilePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Granted, you're relying on Microsoft's implementation of the compression algorithm.  It's not bad, but there may be better ones out there.

Now, what you could do is use the `Image.RawFormat` property of the original image to determine what kind of compression to use during the `Save` method.  I've had varying success having that retrieve the proper method, so I generally use `ImageFormat.Png` as a backup (Png format supports image transparency, Jpeg does not).