# I resized uploaded images but it still have big size

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used to use this code to resize the uploaded image, but when I compared the generated image with other images in other websites, I found that It have large size !!

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(MapPath(filePath));

            int mediumWidth = 350;
            int mediumHeight = mediumWidth * img.Height / img.Width;
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmw = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(img, mediumWidth, mediumHeight);//resize image
            bmw.Save(MapPath("~/image/thumb/") + fileName);
            bmw.Dispose();
```

the generated image have 200 Kb, but in other websites it have 20 kb.. Is there a problem with my code ?

Comment: you are storing the Bitmap Object as a Bitmap-File (.bmp). This is unencoded and large. (Even if you reuse the original Filename and it was png or sth: That does NOT make your new Bitmap become a png). See JpegBitmapEncoder Class for examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Image size increases after creating a smaller resolution of the same image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550159/c-sharp-image-size-increases-after-creating-a-smaller-resolution-of-the-same-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saving it as a bitmap, which is uncompressed. Other websites are probably using jpeg encoding, which results in much smaller file sizes.

Try using [the Save overload which allows specifying encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) instead:

```
bmw.Save(MapPath("~/image/thumb/") + fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```